# Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module, using node-loader in webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, node-modules, sharp

I use `sharp` and `webpack` with `node-loader` but I got this error:

```
D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:150011
  throw new Error(error);
  ^

Error:
Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module

node-loader:
Error: The specified module could not be found.
D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server/33c1e48f049ce3285905e286d212a201.node

- Remove the "node_modules/sharp" directory then run
  "npm install --ignore-scripts=false --verbose" and look for errors
- Consult the installation documentation at https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install
- Search for this error at https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues

    at Object.EmBj (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:150011:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:27:30)
    at Object.Tbcg (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:251632:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:27:30)
    at Module.dMKD (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:324313:63)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:27:30)
    at Module.mWHM (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:405859:77)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:27:30)
    at Module.WXK/ (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:271250:65)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:27:30)
    at D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:118:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:121:10)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47←[39m
```

I removed `sharp` from 'node_modules` then reinstalled it, but got the same error

```
> npm cache clean -f
> npm i --verbose sharp@latest
```

the verbose output of installing sharp is:

```
D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx>npm i --verbose sharp@latest
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Users\\eldeeb\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'i',
npm verb cli   '--verbose',
npm verb cli   'sharp@latest'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@6.9.0
npm info using node@v12.16.2
npm verb npm-session c41d87c77d3d7180
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sharp 1417ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sharp/-/sharp-0.27.0.tgz 644ms
npm timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 6364ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 37ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 1936ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/array-flatten 218ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/array-flatten/-/array-flatten-3.0.0.tgz 278ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/prebuild-install 507ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npmlog 511ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/simple-get 545ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tar-fs 638ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver 643ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-addon-api 654ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/detect-libc 659ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/prebuild-install/-/prebuild-install-6.0.0.tgz 156ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npmlog/-/npmlog-4.1.2.tgz 158ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/simple-get/-/simple-get-4.0.0.tgz 151ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tar-fs/-/tar-fs-2.1.1.tgz 468ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver/-/semver-7.3.4.tgz 471ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/detect-libc/-/detect-libc-1.0.3.tgz 464ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-addon-api/-/node-addon-api-3.1.0.tgz 644ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/are-we-there-yet 122ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/gauge 306ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/console-control-strings 319ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/console-control-strings/-/console-control-strings-1.1.0.tgz 424ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/gauge/-/gauge-2.7.4.tgz 436ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/are-we-there-yet/-/are-we-there-yet-1.1.5.tgz 626ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/delegates 182ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/delegates/-/delegates-1.0.0.tgz 355ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/has-unicode 150ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/wide-align 158ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi 166ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/string-width 170ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi/-/strip-ansi-3.0.1.tgz 216ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/wide-align/-/wide-align-1.1.3.tgz 232ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/has-unicode/-/has-unicode-2.0.1.tgz 242ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/string-width/-/string-width-1.0.2.tgz 323ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/code-point-at 248ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-fullwidth-code-point 260ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-fullwidth-code-point/-/is-fullwidth-code-point-1.0.0.tgz 335ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/code-point-at/-/code-point-at-1.1.0.tgz 364ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/number-is-nan 221ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/number-is-nan/-/number-is-nan-1.0.1.tgz 198ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-regex 294ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-regex/-/ansi-regex-2.1.1.tgz 235ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/string-width/-/string-width-2.1.1.tgz 129ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi/-/strip-ansi-4.0.0.tgz 659ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-fullwidth-code-point/-/is-fullwidth-code-point-2.0.0.tgz 673ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-regex/-/ansi-regex-3.0.0.tgz 167ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/expand-template 196ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/which-pm-runs 441ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/noop-logger 445ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-abi 449ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/napi-build-utils 456ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/simple-get/-/simple-get-3.1.0.tgz 448ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/expand-template/-/expand-template-2.0.3.tgz 263ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp-classic 473ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/github-from-package 479ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp-classic/-/mkdirp-classic-0.5.3.tgz 549ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-abi/-/node-abi-2.19.3.tgz 557ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/noop-logger/-/noop-logger-0.1.1.tgz 575ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/which-pm-runs/-/which-pm-runs-1.0.0.tgz 580ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/github-from-package/-/github-from-package-0.0.0.tgz 561ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/napi-build-utils/-/napi-build-utils-1.0.2.tgz 571ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver/-/semver-5.7.1.tgz 336ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/simple-concat 280ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/decompress-response 299ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/simple-concat/-/simple-concat-1.0.1.tgz 131ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/decompress-response/-/decompress-response-4.2.1.tgz 147ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mimic-response 213ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mimic-response/-/mimic-response-2.1.0.tgz 183ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tar-stream 206ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tar-stream/-/tar-stream-2.2.0.tgz 293ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fs-constants 162ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bl 202ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream 228ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fs-constants/-/fs-constants-1.0.0.tgz 188ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bl/-/bl-4.0.3.tgz 157ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream/-/readable-stream-3.6.0.tgz 154ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer 858ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer/-/buffer-5.7.1.tgz 159ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/decompress-response/-/decompress-response-6.0.0.tgz 245ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mimic-response/-/mimic-response-3.1.0.tgz 105ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Completed in 17386ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree Completed in 20212ms
npm timing stage:generateActionsToTake Completed in 251ms
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\eldeeb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb makeDirectory C:\Users\eldeeb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks creation not in flight; initializing
npm verb makeCacheDir UID & GID are irrelevant on win32
npm verb lock using C:\Users\eldeeb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-ff976866a950c511.lock for D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\node_modules\.stag
ing
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents/-/fsevents-1.2.13.tgz 250ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents/-/fsevents-2.1.3.tgz 260ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents/-/fsevents-1.2.13.tgz 255ms
npm timing action:extract Completed in 304ms
npm info lifecycle undefined~preuninstall: undefined
npm info lifecycle undefined~uninstall: undefined
npm timing action:unbuild Completed in 10ms
npm timing action:remove Completed in 0ms
npm timing action:finalize Completed in 60ms
npm timing action:refresh-package-json Completed in 105ms
npm info lifecycle array-flatten@3.0.0~preinstall: array-flatten@3.0.0
npm info lifecycle semver@7.3.4~preinstall: semver@7.3.4
npm info lifecycle sharp@0.27.0~preinstall: sharp@0.27.0
npm timing action:preinstall Completed in 17ms
npm info linkStuff array-flatten@3.0.0
npm info linkStuff semver@7.3.4
npm verb linkBins [
npm verb linkBins   { semver: 'bin/semver.js' },
npm verb linkBins   'D:\\Downloads\\__projects\\dev\\NodeJs\\@eng-dibo\\ngx\\node_modules\\sharp\\node_modules\\.bin',
npm verb linkBins   false
npm verb linkBins ]
npm info linkStuff sharp@0.27.0
npm timing action:build Completed in 70ms
npm info lifecycle array-flatten@3.0.0~install: array-flatten@3.0.0
npm info lifecycle semver@7.3.4~install: semver@7.3.4
npm info lifecycle sharp@0.27.0~install: sharp@0.27.0

> sharp@0.27.0 install D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\node_modules\sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

info sharp Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.10.5/libvips-8.10.5-win32-x64.tar.br
info sharp Creating D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\node_modules\sharp\build\Release
info sharp Copying DLLs from D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\node_modules\sharp\vendor\8.10.5\lib to D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\nod
e_modules\sharp\build\Release
prebuild-install info begin Prebuild-install version 6.0.0
prebuild-install info looking for cached prebuild @ C:\Users\eldeeb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_prebuilds\9cc5aa-sharp-v0.27.0-napi-v3-win32-x64.tar.gz
prebuild-install info found cached prebuild
prebuild-install info unpacking @ C:\Users\eldeeb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_prebuilds\9cc5aa-sharp-v0.27.0-napi-v3-win32-x64.tar.gz
prebuild-install info unpack resolved to D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\node_modules\sharp\build\Release\sharp.node
prebuild-install info install Successfully installed prebuilt binary!
npm verb lifecycle sharp@0.27.0~install: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
npm verb lifecycle sharp@0.27.0~install: PATH: C:\Users\eldeeb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\No
deJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\node_modules\sharp\node_modules\.bin;D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Pr
ogram Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\
Program Files (x86)\WinMerge;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\
Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yar
n\bin\;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Users\eldeeb\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\eldeeb\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\eldeeb\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin
npm verb lifecycle sharp@0.27.0~install: CWD: D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\node_modules\sharp
npm timing audit submit Completed in 6102ms
npm http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick 6102ms
npm timing audit body Completed in 1ms
npm timing action:install Completed in 30506ms
npm info lifecycle array-flatten@3.0.0~postinstall: array-flatten@3.0.0
npm info lifecycle semver@7.3.4~postinstall: semver@7.3.4
npm info lifecycle sharp@0.27.0~postinstall: sharp@0.27.0
npm timing action:postinstall Completed in 9ms
npm verb unlock done using C:\Users\eldeeb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-ff976866a950c511.lock for D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\node_module
s\.staging
npm timing stage:executeActions Completed in 31157ms
npm timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 19ms
npm timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 58678ms
npm verb saving [ { name: 'sharp', spec: '^0.27.0', save: 'dependencies' } ]
npm verb shrinkwrap skipping write for package.json because there were no changes.
npm info lifecycle undefined~preshrinkwrap: undefined
npm info lifecycle undefined~shrinkwrap: undefined
npm verb shrinkwrap skipping write for package-lock.json because there were no changes.
npm info lifecycle undefined~postshrinkwrap: undefined
npm WARN @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1001.7 requires a peer of @angular/localize@^10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1001.7 requires a peer of ng-packagr@^10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.6.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.6.1 requires a peer of tslib@^1.10.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN jsdom@16.4.0 requires a peer of canvas@^2.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-loading@8.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-loading@8.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@10.0.1 requires a peer of node-sass@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@10.0.1 requires a peer of fibers@>= 3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-subresource-integrity@1.4.1 requires a peer of html-webpack-plugin@^2.21.0 || ~3 || >=4.0.0-alpha.2 <5 but none is installed. You must install peer depen
dencies yourself.
npm WARN ws@7.4.0 requires a peer of bufferutil@^4.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ws@7.4.0 requires a peer of utf-8-validate@^5.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm verb notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
npm verb notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
npm verb notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
npm verb notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm verb notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
npm verb notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
npm verb notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
npm verb notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm verb notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
npm verb notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
npm verb notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
npm verb notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64

+ sharp@0.27.0
added 3 packages from 69 contributors and audited 1986 packages in 60.317s
found 11 vulnerabilities (7 low, 1 moderate, 3 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm timing npm Completed in 60904ms
npm info ok
```

I added `node-loader` to webpack:

```
config.module.rules.push(
    { test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
    {
      test: /\.node$/,
      use: "node-loader"
    }
  );
```

OS: windows 8.1

this issue is specially occures with angular, I just created a brand new angular project and enabled universal app.

**minimal reproduction:**

https://github.com/eng-dibo/ng-sharp-issue

**steps to run this reproduction:**

1- clone this repo  https://github.com/eng-dibo/ng-sharp-issue

2- inatsll packages `npm i`

3- build the server `npm run build:server:dev`

-> {optional} to build the whole project (browser & server) and serve it `npm run start`

-> the script `build:ssr` has been renamed to `build:server` or `build:server:dev` for clarification.

this generates `dist` dir contains `main.js` and `sharp-*.node` files

4- run the server `node dist/main`

```
Error:
Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module

node-loader:
Error: The specified module could not be found.
//sharp-ac5709806d227d1d966f7f0b76814d78.node
```

if we removed `node-loader` from webpack config, we will get `error: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)` as mentioned in the detailed "steps of creating this repo" step-by-step below.

**steps of creating this reproduction:** (for reference)

1- create new angular project:

```
ng new ngx
ng serve -o //<-- success
```

2- enable universal app

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
npm run build:ssr & npm run serve <--success
```

3- add sharp to `server.ts`

```
//server.ts
import * as sharp from "sharp"
sharp('./image.jpg')

npm run build:ssr <-- faild, error: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
```

4- use node-loader to load .node file (inside sharp package), we need to use custom webpack to modify webpack configuration in Angular

```
npm i -D @angular-builders/custom-webpack node-loader ts-loader
```

```
//angular.json
{
...
server:{
  "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:server",
   "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.server.config.js"
            }
  }
}

}
```

```
//webpack.server.config.js (simplified)
module.exports = (config, options) => {
   //remove webpack config from Angular, except 'resolve', and add rules (ts-loader, node-loader)

config = {
    mode: "development",
    resolve: config.resolve,
    entry: {
      main: ["./server.ts"]
    },
    target: "node",
    stats: { colors: false },
    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
        {
          test: /\.node$/,
          loader: "node-loader",
          options: { name: "[name]-[contenthash].[ext]" }
        }
      ]
    }
  };

return config;

}
```

```
npm run build:ssr <-- faild
```

Answer (score 5):

For people with the followed bug:

```
"Something went wrong installing the \"sharp\" module",
"",
"Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-linux-arm64v8.node'"
```

and/or with M2 Pro, try to rebuild twice, the following commands work for me:

```
npm install sharp
npm rebuild --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp
npm rebuild --platform=linux --arch=arm64 sharp
```

Now the release package could be used on Amazon Lambda.
To be sure, that everything in in place, check the directory in node_modules

```
node_modules/sharp/build/Release
```

and check if these files exist

```
node_modules/sharp/build/release/sharp-darwin-arm64v8.node
node_modules/sharp/build/release/sharp-linux-x64v8.node
node_modules/sharp/build/release/sharp-linux-arm64v8.node
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The auto-generated help has 'Install for the current linuxmusl-x64 runtime: "npm install --platform=linuxmusl --arch=x64 sharp"' which didn't work for me but npm rebuild did.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the "sharp" directory in "node_modules" then run
"npm install --ignore-scripts=false --verbose sharp" and that should work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

[Solution] the issue is solved, it occurred because 'node-externals' module resolve the path of 'package.json' wrong.

it assumes that the file package.json is located in the same directory of the current working directory 'CWD', but it may not, as in my case (a monorepo).

in short words:
if you run the build command from other dir rather than your project's root (such as the workspace root), node-externals plugin will use the package.json file in your workspace's root (i.e: CWD), which doesn't contain 'sharp', so it will not add it to webpack.external[]

Comment: had monorepo setup too. drives me crazy. trying the `options.additionalModuleDirs (='[]')` options. should work